# Error: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:" while requesting https call via rx-http-client

Tags: node.js, https, rxjs

In my node js application used the rx-http-client package for http/https requests.
but after run the file it gives me that Error: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:".
Whats the issue? i can't figure out..

Comment: share some code please

Comment: var rxHttpClient = require('rx-http-client');

rxHttpClient.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'+this.sourceName + '?fields=posts.limit(30){picture,full_picture,link,source,shares,created_time,message,name}&' + realAccessToken);